# MacOS, export email folder with each message to its own file

Tags: macos, applescript, mail.app, email

Is there a good way to export a Mac email folder so that each email message goes into a separate file?  The only way I can think of is to export the folder using the "Export Mailbox" menu item, and then write a script (shell script for example) which will parse the email file and split it when it finds a new mail header.  It seems a new message starts with every line which starts with "From " (including the space).   Is this the best way?

Answer (score 1):

[Procmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail) is a possibility, but a) it's no longer maintained, and b) it may or may not run under macos. There are some other programs listed on [procmail's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail) that may be useful.

But, just as a guess, I think you might have to "roll your own". If you know Python, you can use the [mailbox library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mailbox.html).